# ios 10 app crashes when accessing camera

Tags: swift, ios10, xcode8.2

I am new to ios. I am building an app which requires camera access, and according to new requirements I have already added following camera permission in info.plist but still I am getting following exception. I have also tried cleaning and reinstalling app on my phone. Does any one know how to fix this.

info.plit
[image]

> This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive
>   data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain
>   an NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the
>   user how the app uses this data.

Comment: Try changing your value on the privacy key to be what the error says - a simple string explaining how the app will use the camera. In my app I say "Used to capture new image for photo effect". I'm thinking the *$(PRODUCT_NAME)* may be the cause.

Comment: Yes i changed the description to some text and it did not work. than i cleaned build folder and run the app again on my phone. it worked successfully :) thanks

Comment: Glad you got it working. Was it the *$(PRODUCT_NAME)* or the clean up that did the trick? (I'm going to keep this in my tool set for future apps.)

Comment: Did you try on Real device? not Simulation ?

Comment: The last comment suggest it was tried on a device, and it's now working. If you tried to use a camera on a simulator (without proper checks) I think you'll get a *very* different error, as it doesn't have a camera. (I have a check for just that and pop up something to say there's no camera on this device.

Comment: @dfd it was $(PRODUCT_NAME). Vahid was trying on Device not simulator.

Comment: I'll add this as an answer then for future developers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your privacy key value contains **$(PRODUCT_NAME)**, which appears to be the reason that this error (only for iOS 10+) appears.

Change your privacy key value to a *pure* string like "Used to capture new image for photo effect" and it should correct it.