# NSCameraUsageDescription is not working

Tags: ios, xcode, info-plist

I am trying to open up the user's camera, but whenever I try to open the camera I get this error, "The app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data." I have already added Privacy - Camera Usage Description along with a value such as "I need to use your camera" to the info.plist file, but I am still getting this error.
Here is my source code for info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Needed to receive your current location.</string>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Need to use camera for AR</string>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

***I have found the solution. I had to go into "info" and add the privacy key in custom IOS Target Properties

Comment: There was a question similar to this 1-2 weeks ago, and it turned out the issue was with the description. Could you post your XML (source) plist code?

Comment: @dfd should be referring to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597172/ios-10-app-crashes-when-accessing-camera

Comment: You said the value was "I need to use your camera", can you state exactly what is the value?

Comment: I edited it to have the source code, thanks! @paper1111

Comment: The value looks good. I really hate to think this is an Apple bug, but here's my value: "Used to capture new image for photo effect". Slightly longer, (maybe) slightly less abrupt. The only things I can think are: (1) Delete the app from the device and start fresh. Maybe they declined? (2) Try my value, because it works? Really strange.

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly after iOS 10 you have to define access to all hardware. Most likely, you will be missing the "Privacy-Microphone Usage Description". switch to the "Organizer" and look at the crash reports on the device and add all the privacy errors listed there.

Comment: I went ahead and added all of the privacy settings but still not luck.

Comment: There's a now-deleted comment (which I down-voted only after a reply telling me I was wrong) that also stated adding the Microphone privacy setting. My second comment added a link addressing what changed in iOS 10. Truth is, my approved app from last year - upgraded to iOS10  and Swift 3 in September - has had no crashes and only contained privacy keys for Camera and Photo Album, not Microphone. (1) I never heard of this privacy key before - I wouldn't because my app is photo oriented and doesn't care about the microphone. (2) The OP doesn't speak of using the microphone.

Comment: @ZacharyCheshire have you tried looking at the error log?